# Find programmatically the sub-interval that has the most eruptions

Tags: r

`faithful` is a built-in data set in `r`.

I have to compute the  sub-interval that has the most eruptions.

I have tried it by the following way:

```
 vct <- faithful$eruptions
 range(vct)
 vct.cut <- cut(vct,seq(1.5,5.5,by=0.5),right=FALSE)
 freq <- table(vct.cut)

  y <- sort(freq,decreasing=TRUE)

 #the  sub-interval that has the most eruptions.
  y[1]
```

Is the procedure correct? I am seeking for a better way to Find programmatically the  sub-interval that has the most eruptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `which.max`.

```
names(freq)[which.max(freq)]
```